# Concatenating elements of an array in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, concatenation

Hey ive run into a troubling problem basically I have an array `Dim array() as String = {"Team1, "Team2", "Team3", "Team4", "Team5" }`

My goal is to concatenate the strings in even pairs with the string "vs" **AND** if there is an odd number of pairs to concatenate the odd element in the array with the string "Bye" **So** im trying to get my output to look like this `Team1 vs Team2, Team3 vs Team4, Team5 vs Bye`

I know that I need to use loops however im getting confused on how i can get the  unknown number of elements in the original array into even pairs of 2 so that i can concatenate the strings! Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a for loop and use a step of 2. Use a StringBuilder in order to assemble the final string.

```
Dim array() as String = { "Team1", "Team2", "Team3", "Team4", "Team5" }
Dim sb As New StringBuilder() 
For i = 0 To array.Length - 1 Step 2
    Dim s1 As String = array(i) 
    Dim s2 As String = If(i + 1 < array.Length, array(i + 1), "Bye")
    sb.Append(s1).Append(" vs ").Append(s2).Append(", ")
Next
If sb.Length > = 2 Then
    sb.Length -= 2
End If
Dim result = sb.ToString() ' ==> "Team1 vs Team2, Team3 vs Team4, Team5 vs Bye"
```

Comment: thats it thank you so much! i see how you used the loops to get the end result!

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid loops and use LINQ. Here's what I would do:

```
Dim array As String() = { "Team1", "Team2", "Team3", "Team4", "Team5" }

Dim working = array
If working.Length Mod 2 = 1 Then
    working = working.Concat({ "Bye" }).ToArray()
End If

Dim output = _
    working.Where(Function (x, n) n Mod 2 = 0) _
        .Zip(working.Where(Function (x, n) n Mod 2 = 1), _
            Function (x1, x2) String.Format("{0} vs {1}", x1, x2)) _
    .ToArray()
```

This gives:

[image: output]

Another alternative way of doing this with LINQ is this:

```
Dim output = _
    working _
        .Select(Function (x, n) New With { .Team = x, .Group = n \ 2 }) _
        .GroupBy(Function (x) x.Group, Function (x) x.Team) _
        .Select(Function (xs) String.Join(" vs ", xs)) _
        .ToArray()
```

With 8 teams:

```
Team1 vs Team2 
Team3 vs Team4 
Team5 vs Team6 
Team7 vs Team8
```

With 3 teams:

```
Team1 vs Team2 
Team3 vs Bye
```

With 10,001 teams:

```
Team1 vs Team2 
Team3 vs Team4 
Team5 vs Team6 
...
Team9997 vs Team9998 
Team9999 vs Team10000 
Team10001 vs Bye
```

If you need it as a string, rather than an array, then just do this:

```
Dim text = String.Join(", ", output)
```

This gives you this kind of thing:

> Team1 vs Team2, Team3 vs Team4, Team5 vs Team6, Team7 vs Team8, Team9 vs Team10, Team11 vs Team12, Team13 vs Team14, Team15 vs Team16, Team17 vs Bye

Comment: This would be awesome except that I dont know that there will be a team1 team2 team3 team4 team5 there could be 500 or 5000 teams or there could be 2 or 3 teams otherwise this looks great because the output is correct

Comment: Cool use of Linq. I didn't know of this overload of `Where`. Thanks for showing it.

Comment: @ChristianBartram - This works great no matter how many teams.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment a For loop by 2 by adding a Step parameter. But instead of loop to Count - 1, you should loop to one-half of that. This depends somewhat on the odd/evenness of the number of teams. When concatenating, use the loop parameter and the parameter plus 1 to access the array elements. Example:

```
dim game as string = teams(i) & teams(i + 1)
```